# Android - Layout is not working properly

Tags: image, android-layout

I want to load a layout based on screen size.

**My configuration**

> Android 2.2
>
> Small Screen QVGA(240x320), low density(120)
>
> Image resolution is 240x320

**res/layout-small/myimg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ImageView 
        android:src="@drawable/simage" 
        android:id="@+id/imageView1" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
```

But when i run the app the screen is not completely covered by the image, a small margin is present on left and right side of screen.

I also followind the link below but the problem is still there

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers

Can anyone tell me where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Probably your image no cover all screen. May be image have a transparent borders or have no exactly right size. Also you can use a `android:scaleType="fitXY"` with `ImageView`
   **Added:**
2. Suggest you use a `ldpi` quilifier instead of `small`.